# Chrome extension API's for read file on a DFS or NFS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, nfs, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I search for a long time how to read file on a DFS through a chrome extension.

I want to check in a google sheets which list file, if there are present on a NFS or on a DFS.

I find fileSystem Chrome's api, but it seems, that it didn't do the job.

Thanks in advance.

Johan

Comment: *what* didn't do the job? please show us exactly what *did not* work. we can't fix it if you don't show us.

Comment: Hi @Occam'sRazor, i will post tomorrow an example for my problem, thanks for your time

Comment: Hi i’ve aborted thaïs solution. I use a gscript that’s calling an api. It works on my laptop but not on developpment environment. It’s impossible to call a local api from gscript :/